# Out of memory with python IDLE

Tags: python, macos, memory, interpreter, python-idle

When I have a relatively large data(~a page of lines), ie. a long `str`, very long `int`, `dict`, or a `list`*(mainly dicts and lists)*, and I wanted to check something from the data by using `print`,
my IDLE always run out of memory and starts to not respond and not print anything at first. But eventually it prints, but not respond every time I scroll the screen. I needed to print the data when I want to see what's in the data after I use `json` to parse it.

I been getting around this by printing it to a file instead of the screen, but it's very tiresome and I would like to avoid doing that. I recently realized that if I run the same script from Terminal it prints properly. If there's any way to fix this please tell me. And if not, please recommend a better interpreter for me.

I'm running Python 3.6 with it's default IDLE on Mac Sierra.

Comment: have you tried using the python REPL $ python?

Comment: Unless you have seen an 'out of memory' exception, the title is wrong.  Are you trying to print long or very long lines -- over, say, 1000 chars.  Tcl/Tk Text widgets are optimized for screen-sized lines.  They bog down for 'long' lines.  But they will handle at least 500,000 short lines (the most I tested).   On Windows, the console does not choke on long lines but will only keep a finite number of lines in a ring buffer.  The maximum is 9999 and the default is 300.  When the 301st line is printed, the 1st is deleted, and so on.  I do not know about Mac terminals.